# JavaScript, what is wrong with this?

Tags: javascript

This is my JS code, I would realy appreciate if someone would help me, because this code is not even running and I don't know why.

```
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
    var can = document.getElementById('Canvas1'); 
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 250, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: what is ( ` )  before <canvas id .....

Answer (score 1):

```
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="400" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>
var can = document.getElementById('Canvas1'); 
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 50);
</script>
```

You missed border in canvas so u was not seeing o/p

and also you starting `fillRect` at 100(height) that is your end point of rect so u are not able to see the result.

Remember

`ctx.fillRect(p1, p2 ,p3 , p4);`

p1 = Start point X

p2 = Start point Y

p3 = width of your rectangle that should be less than or equal to Canvas width.

p4 = Height of your rectangle that should be less than or equal to Canvas height.